# Why DropDownList event fires after another event

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a `DropDownList` in my page:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPra" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="chosen-select" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Practice_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Practice_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ddlCli.SelectedItem.Text);
}
```

I also have an `UpdatePanel` which has a `GridView that displays some data with links. The issue I am having is when the page loads and I change the option from the select drop down, I don't get an alert but when I click on anything inside the`UpdatePanel` the alert is displayed.

How do I fix it so that the `DropDownList` works independent from the `UpdatePanel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why DropDownList event fires after another event?

Because you have not set [`AutoPostBack="true"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx), it is `false` by default. That means that it will not post back immediately after the user selected another item. But the event will be triggered on the next postback anyway, independent of the control that caused it.

Comment: Just noticed it. Thank you.